# SQLLITE не выполняет даже простой вопрос "Select * from <имя таблицы>". Таблица есть и не пустая. С#

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

Я изучаю Xamarin и мне нужно, чтобы моё приложение обладало встроенной Бд SqlLite. Сказано сделано - данные успешно закидываются(отладкой глядел , используя Эмулятор  Genymotion ), а вот запрос "Select * from <имя таблицы>" в методе

database.Query<имя таблицы>("Select * from <имя таблицы>").AsEnumerable();

выдает всегда пустой результат! Что за ересь? 
Низкий поклон любому, кто поможет в этой патовой ситуации)

Все делал по инструкции вот тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/mt736454.aspx , отчего код практически не отличается , кроме страницы и отсутствием некоторых колонок в таблице, да и методы работы с этой таблицей :только добавить и выдать - но это не существенные мелочи)

p.s А если Я в запросе пишу не существующую таблицу или другое непотребство - Sql ругается....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасение утопающих дело лап самих утопающих! Только что просто почитал вверх кода... Оказывается в инструкции не хватает команды insert в методе Add. Чуток поменял этот важный метод

```
public void AddNewCustomer()
{
 Customer xs = new Customer     
 {
   CompanyName = "Company name...",
   PhysicalAddress = "Address...",
   Country = "Country..."
 };

this.Customers.Add(xs);

database.Insert(xs);
}
```

Вот такие качественные инструкции есть на msdn ... Вроде как там где то опечатка мелкая ещё была ....

Все народ, вопрос снимаю) Робит

P.s. Спасибо модератору за правку)